List all IDs starting with a specified string followed by a number, remove the string, and get the biggest number value
A page contains dozens of elements with IDs that look like: <a id="msg{number}"></a> The IDs are unique and are in no particular order, for example:
<a id="msg988755"></a>
<a id="msg129"></a>
<a id="msg7756501"></a>
<a id="msg745"></a>
<a id="msg657550"></a>
<a id="msg1148"></a>
<a id="msg87905541"></a>
<a id="msg745102"></a>
<a id="msg31780"></a>
<a id="msg2657588"></a>
<a id="msg8895"></a>

My goal is to use pure JS find the ID with the biggest number (after removing the 'msg' part from the ID), meaning that the result of the script should be this number: 87905541
I think the script should run a query to find all IDs that start with 'msg', eg. document.querySelectorAll('[id^="msg"]')]; but from there I'm stuck. I read that this function could find the biggest number: Math.max(num)

You're on the right track, you can use the NodeList elements that you select with [id^="msg"] and pass them into Array.from() where you can use the second mapping argument to map each element to its id minus the msg component (removed using .replace()). Once you have an array of just your number components, you can spread this array into Math.max() to get the largest number from the array:


const max = Math.max(...Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('[id^="msg"]'), 
  ({id}) => id.replace("msg", "")
));

console.log(max);
<a id="msg988755"></a>
<a id="msg129"></a>
<a id="msg7756501"></a>
<a id="msg745"></a>
<a id="msg657550"></a>
<a id="msg1148"></a>
<a id="msg87905541"></a>
<a id="msg745102"></a>
<a id="msg31780"></a>
<a id="msg2657588"></a>
<a id="msg8895"></a>




Thank you - but is it in pure/Vanilla JS? I put this entire code on a test .html page and the result is: -Infinity. Perhaps this {id} in the code causes that..

is it in pure/Vanilla JS yes it is - the fact that you got -Infinity means that you've done something that results in Math.max running with no arguments - which means Array.from(...etc...) has returned an empty array - perhaps you're running the code before the elements exist

When I removed the 3 dots before 'Array', ie. put it this way: max = Math.max(...Array.from( then the result is 0. I just copy-paste the entire code on a test html page.

Ok, I figured it out - the <script></script> should be on the bottom of the page, now it works!

An alternative is:


<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <a id="msg988755"></a>
    <a id="msg129"></a>
    <a id="msg7756501"></a>
    <a id="msg745"></a>
    <a id="msg657550"></a>
    <a id="msg1148"></a>
    <a id="msg87905541"></a>
    <a id="msg745102"></a>
    <a id="msg31780"></a>
    <a id="msg2657588"></a>
    <a id="msg8895"></a>
  </body>

  <script>
    const arrID=[];
    const collID= document.querySelectorAll('[id^=msg]');

    for (var i = 0; i < collID.length; i++) {
        var temp= collID[i].id;
        arrID.push(temp.replace('msg',''));      
    }
    
    console.log(Math.max(...arrID));
  </script>




You can sort
Getting the element without extracting the ID


window.addEventListener('load', () => { // after the page loads and the elements are present
  const largest = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a[id^=msg]'))
    .sort((a, b) => a.id.localeCompare(b.id, 'en', { numeric: true })) // the compare needs to take the numbers into account
    .pop();
  largest.classList.add('largest');
});
.largest {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
<pre>
<a id="msg988755">msg988755</a>
<a id="msg129">msg129</a>
<a id="msg7756501">msg7756501</a>
<a id="msg745">msg745</a>
<a id="msg657550">msg657550</a>
<a id="msg1148">msg1148</a>
<a id="msg87905541">msg87905541</a>
<a id="msg745102">msg745102</a>
<a id="msg31780">msg31780</a>
<a id="msg2657588">msg2657588</a>
<a id="msg8895">msg8895</a>
</pre>



Getting just the largest number from the ID


window.addEventListener('load', () => { // after the page loads and the elements are present
  const largest = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a[id^=msg]'))
    .map(anchor => anchor.id)
    .sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, 'en', { numeric: true })); // the compare needs to take the numbers into account
  console.log(largest.pop().replace('msg',''));
});
<a id="msg988755"></a>
<a id="msg129"></a>
<a id="msg7756501"></a>
<a id="msg745"></a>
<a id="msg657550"></a>
<a id="msg1148"></a>
<a id="msg87905541"></a>
<a id="msg745102"></a>
<a id="msg31780"></a>
<a id="msg2657588"></a>
<a id="msg8895"></a>




Simply:


console.log(Math.max(...[...document.getElementsByTagName("a")].map(item => parseInt(item.id.substring("msg".length)))))
<a id="msg988755"></a>
<a id="msg129"></a>
<a id="msg7756501"></a>
<a id="msg745"></a>
<a id="msg657550"></a>
<a id="msg1148"></a>
<a id="msg87905541"></a>
<a id="msg745102"></a>
<a id="msg31780"></a>
<a id="msg2657588"></a>
<a id="msg8895"></a>



Explanation:

we will call Math.max, just like you predicted, the question is only what we will pass to it
the ... before the parameter converts an array to values, like at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max
document.getElementsByTagName("a") gets the anchors, of course, you might need some other selector in your real code if you have some anchors that you want to select and you want to avoid selecting some others, but here I selected them by the tag name due to not having any other specification
the ... converts the array-like-object returned by getElementsByTagName into an actual array, so we can call .map(), a method available for arrays
item => parseInt(item.id.substring("msg".length)) is an arrow function passed to .map() which will run for all items in the array and for each, it will get the value after msg, convert it to int
so the result is an array of integers which represent the numeric value of each ids as specified in the question and we destructure this array into parameters to be passed to Math.max

